# How to improve datatable loading performance when datatable has a rendered chart inside each column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable rendered with a chart on each column, the datatable generated from ajax response data having more than 1000 records. Rendering the chart inside the columns results in performance issues. How to improve the performance?

Here is the code i use:

**ajax:**

```
var resData = [];
$.ajax({
    'type': "POST",
    'url': "CoxModel/processTypes/execution",
    'data': dataList,
    'beforeSend': function() {
        $(".graphloadertraining").show();
    },
    'success': function(data) {
        response = $.parseJSON(data);
        response = response.data
        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(response);
                var count = JSON.parse(jsonObject).length;
                resData.push(value);
            })
        variableData(resData);
        // return data;
    }
});
```

**chart generate:**

```
function variableData(data) {
    $(".graphloader").hide();

    var newAry = {};
    var newAryy = [];

    i = 0;
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        var pd = value.PROCESSDATE;
        var pt = value.PROCESS_TYPE;
        var mn = value.MODELNAME;
        var vn = value.VARIABLENAME;
        var vc = value.VARIABLECONTRIBUTION;

        if (!newAry[pt]) {
            newAry[pt] = {};
        }
        if (!newAry[pt][mn]) {
            newAry[pt][mn] = {};
        }
        if (!newAry[pt][mn][vn]) {
            newAry[pt][mn][vn] = {};
        }

        if (!newAry[pt][mn][vn]['pd']) {
            newAry[pt][mn][vn]['pd'] = [];
        }

        if (!newAry[pt][mn][vn]['vc']) {
            newAry[pt][mn][vn]['vc'] = [];
        }

        newAry[pt][mn][vn]['pd'].push(pd);
        newAry[pt][mn][vn]['vc'].push(vc);

        i++;
    });

    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#cox-model-modelgraph-variable")) {
        $('#cox-model-modelgraph-variable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
    }

    tableWithChart = $('#cox-model-modelgraph-variable tbody');
    tableBodyContent = '';

    $.each(newAry, function(pType, pTypeValue) {
        $.each(pTypeValue, function(mName, mNameValue) {
            $.each(mNameValue, function(vName, vNameValue) {
                tableBodyContent += '<tr><td>' + pType + '</td>';
                tableBodyContent += '<td>' + mName + '</td>';
                tableBodyContent += '<td>' + vName + '</td>';
                tableBodyContent += '<td><div  id="model-graph-' + pType + '-' + mName + '-' + vName + '" data-value="' + vNameValue.pd + '|' + vNameValue.vc + '"></div></td>';
                tableBodyContent += '</tr>';
            });

        });
    });

    tableWithChart.html(tableBodyContent);

    $(".chartContainer").empty();
    $("#cox-model-modelgraph-variable").dataTable({
        pageLength: 50,
        deferRender: true,
        processing: true,
        "columns": [{
            "title": "PROCESS TYPE"
        }, {
            "title": "MODEL NAME"
        }, {
            "title": "VARIABLE NAME"
        }, {
            "sortable": false,
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                dataId = $(data).attr('id');
                dataValue = $(data).data('value');
                return $("<div></div>", {
                    "id": dataId
                }).append(modelGraphVariableChart(dataId, dataValue)).prop("outerHTML");
            }
        }]
    });
    $(".graphloader").hide();
    $("#cox-model-modelgraph-variable tbody").removeClass('tr-loading');
}

function modelGraphVariableChart(chartContainer, chartValue) {
    chartValue = chartValue.split('|');

    for (i in chartValue) {
        chartValue[i] = chartValue[i].split(',');
        for (j in chartValue[i]) {
            if (chartValue[i][j] == '') chartValue[i][j] = 0;
            else if (parseFloat(chartValue[i][j]) == chartValue[i][j]) {
                chartValue[i][j] = parseFloat(chartValue[i][j]);
            } else {
                chartValue[i][j] = chartValue[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    newchart[chartContainer] = Highcharts.chart(chartContainer, {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            height: 100,
            scrollablePlotArea: {
                minWidth: 300,
                maxWidth: 300,
                scrollPositionX: 1
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: chartValue[0]
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: false,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            endOnTick: false,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            alternateGridColor: null,
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: null
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'VC',
                data: chartValue[1]
            }]
    });

    return newchart;
}
```

**My table looks like this:**

[image: table]

Comment: Any update on this?